# How do i find the biggest number that are not in a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that gives you the average, total, and biggest number entered. I am stuck at the biggest number part. My numbers are not in a list, so I don't know how to find the biggest one.

```
num=0 
total=0 
average=0 
count=0 

while True: 
  num=input("enter a number:")
  num=int(num) 
  if num==-999: 
    break 
  total=total + num
  count=count+1 
  biggest = max(total)

average=total/count 

#print the results
print("the total is:", total)
print("the biggest number is:", biggest)
print("the average is:", average)
```

I would like it to print the biggest number at the end.

Thanks

Comment: You are summing them and they are not in a list as well. Using a similar idea you can just remember the maximum element that you saw between the inputs.

Comment: You don't need a list. Just add another number `biggest = -sys.maxsize` (initialize it at the beginning, together with the others), and every time you read `num` do `if num > buggest: biggest = num`. You will also need `import sys`.

Comment: Are you just using `-999` to exit the loop and get the print statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me share you a solution for your problem. (Take a look at the if clause after the check of the number being "-999"). Feel free to ask if you have any questions! Hope it helps you

```
num=0 
total=0 
average=0 
count=0
biggest=0 

while True: 
  num=input("enter a number:")
  num=int(num) 
  if num==-999: 
    break
  if num > biggest:
    biggest = num
  total=total + num
  count=count+1 

average=total/count 

#print the results
print("the total is:", total)
print("the biggest number is:", biggest)
print("the average is:", average)
```

Comment: My test would be to enter -1, -2, -3, -999

Comment: Then you could set the biggest variable to be None. So at the beginning you have it set at None, and you do an if like this:
if biggest is None or num > biggest:
    biggest = num

Comment: Thank you! This one helped alot

Answer (score 2):

```
num=0 
total=0 
average=0 
count=0
biggest=0

while True: 
  num=input("enter a number:")
  num=int(num) 
  if num==-999: 
    break 
  total=total + num
  count=count+1 
  if num > biggest:
      biggest = num

average=total/count 

#print the results
print("the total is:", total)
print("the biggest number is:", biggest)
print("the average is:", average)
```

Comment: @abc That is a weakness of my answer, but the original code has similar weaknesses, e.g. not testing the result of `int()`.  If the questioner wants to address those weaknesses, I hope my answer helps them do so.

Comment: That's at least an attitude. :) However - the question is `How do i find the biggest number that are not in a list?` not `How many people can give me a hint which works only in half of the cases...?`

Answer (score 1):

you can just:

```
if num > biggest:
   biggest = num
```

Comment: biggest is not defined before your conditional, so this will throw an error

Comment: no, as far as I can see it is not. `biggest = max(total)` is wrong code, which they ask to be replaced by sth that works.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I saw wrong, but he clearly knows how to do that, and since he's using negative numbers to end the program,it is up to him to decide the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

initialize biggest with a value which can not be bigger than any input:

```
import numpy
biggest = -np.inf
```

replace

```
biggest = max(total)
```

by

```
biggest = max(biggest, num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable `biggest` before the loop:

```
biggest = -9999
```

This should be initialized to something smaller than any of the numbers that the program is going to encounter. The above assumes that -9999 is such a number which is a bad assumption in general; there are better ways to accomplish that, e.g. one of the comments suggests

```
import sys
biggest = -sys.maxint
```

That's the negative of the maximum integer value that this implementation can represent.

Then in the body of the loop, update the variable `biggest`:

```
biggest = max(biggest, num)
```

If `num` is bigger than `biggest` then `max(biggest, num)` will return the value of `num` so that `biggest` will get the value of `num`. If it is smaller, `biggest` will stay unchanged. In other words, `biggest` remembers the largest value seen so far. At the end of the loop, it will then hold the largest value seen, period.

Comment: My test would be to enter `-100000, -200000, -300000, -999`

Comment: This would fail if all the numbers are less than -9999. Also, your answer lacks detail: you should describe how your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Here idited your code to be right

```
num=0 
total=0 
average=0 
count=0 
biggest = None  ### added

while True: 
  num=input("enter a number:")
  num=int(num)
  if num==-999: 
    break 
  total=total + num
  count=count+1 

  #biggest = max(total)   Here where was you wrong
  if num > biggest :   #### added
     biggest = num     #### added

average=total/count 

#print the results
print("the total is:", total)
print("the biggest number is:", biggest)
print("the average is:", average)
```

Comment: My test would be to enter `-1, -2, -3, -999`

Comment: Then your program will crash throwing an error `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Comment: Yes , your 're write

Answer (score 0):

If you look into some other methods you can get a lot more functionality and do even more with your program, take a look at this code and try to take some ideas it could make your task and future tasks easier for you

```
numbers = []

print("Enter any non-number to perform calculations.\n")

while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        numbers.append(num)

    except ValueError:
        break

total = sum(numbers)
average = total/len(numbers)
biggest = max(numbers)

print(f"\nThe total is: {total}")
print(f"The biggest number is: {biggest}")
print(f"The average is: {average}")
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 biggest.py
> Enter any non-number to perform calculations.
>
> Enter a number: 1
> Enter a number: 2
> Enter a number: 3
> Enter a number: 4
> Enter a number: -1
> Enter a number: 2
> Enter a number: 3
> Enter a number: q
>
> The total is: 14
> The biggest number is: 4
> The average is: 2.0
> ```